# Can Someone help me to create Short Code for displaying a category posts

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

Can Someone help me to create shortcode for displaying a category posts...

```
// Custom Post type coding starts from here (for my remembrance)
function diwp_arts_custom_post_type(){
    // here I am setting labels for custom post type (for my remembrance)
    $labels = array(
                     'name' => 'Arts',
                     'singular_name' => 'Art',
                     'add_new'    => 'Add New Post',
                     'add_new_item' => 'Enter Art Details',
                     'all_items' => 'All Arts',
                     'featured_image' => 'Add Feature Image',
                     'set_featured_image' => 'Set Feature Image',
                     'remove_featured_image' => 'Remove Feature Image'
                   );
    // here I am setting Options for custom post type (for my remembrance)
    $args = array(    
                    'public' => true,
                    'label'       => 'Arts',
                    'labels'      => $labels,
                    'description' => ' Arts is a collection of all Art and their info',
                    'menu_icon'      => 'dashicons-art',    
                    'supports'   => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
                    'capability_type' => 'page',
                 );
    register_post_type('arts', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'diwp_arts_custom_post_type' );

function wpdocs_create_book_tax() {
    register_taxonomy( 'Types', 'arts', array(
        'label'        => __( 'Types', 'textdomain' ),
        'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'arts' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpdocs_create_book_tax', 0 );
//Custom post type coding has been ended here (for my remembrance)
// >> Coding to create shortcode (for my remembrance)

function diwp_create_shortcode_arts_post_type(){ 
    $args = array(
                    'post_type'      => 'arts',
                    'posts_per_page' => '10',
                    'publish_status' => 'published',
                 );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($query->have_posts()) :
        while($query->have_posts()) :
            $query->the_post() ;             
        $result .= '<div class="art-item">';
        $result .= '<div class="art-image">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
        $result .= '<div class="art-name">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
        $result .= '<div class="art-desc">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
        $result .= '</div>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    return $result;            
}
add_shortcode( 'arts-list', 'diwp_create_shortcode_arts_post_type' );
// shortcode code has been ended here (for my remembrance)
```

Comment: Moiz, can you add what specifically is going wrong?

Comment: I see at least one error: `'publish_status' => 'published'` should be `'post_status' => 'publish'`.

Comment: Actually I can't find out what's the error in this code, I have to create a shortcode to display a category, can you solve this problem?